# convert text to unicode char

Tags: objective-c

I have some texts

```
\u652f\u6301\u3002
```

I hope it can display the relevant unicode chars

I try to use

```
[s   stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

to decode but no result

Welcome any comment

Comment: What is it that you want?  What do you mean by "relevant unicode chars"?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str =@"\u652f\u6301\u3002";
NSLog(@"%@",str);  // Output: 支持。

NSString *str =@"\\u652f\\u6301\\u3002";
NSLog(@"%@",str);    // Output: \u652f\u6301\u3002
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure of what you are trying to do.
but in Ruby I could do the following.

```
ruby> a = Iconv.iconv( "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE","\\u652f\\u6301\\u3002")
=> ["\347\225\234\343\224\266\346\230\262\347\225\234\343\214\266\343\204\260\347\225\234\343\200\263\343\210\260"]
ruby> puts a
畜㔶昲畜㌶㄰畜〳㈰
```

hope this helps.